# AWS - Sage Maker Random Cut Forest

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science, amazon-sagemaker

I have aws cpu-utilization data which NAB used to create Anomaly Detection using AWS- SageMaker Random Cut Forest. i am able to execute it but i need a deeper solution for the Hyper Parameter Tuning. I have gone through the AWS- Documentation but need to understand the Hyper Parameter selection. are the parameters an educated Guess or Do we need to calculate co_disp's mean and standard deviation in order to infer the parameters.

Thanks in Advance.

I have tried 100 Trees and 512/256 tree_size to detect anomalies but how to infer these parameters

```py
    # Set tree parameters
    num_trees = 50
    shingle_size = 48
    tree_size = 512

    # Create a forest of empty trees
    forest = []
    for _ in range(num_trees):
        tree = rrcf.RCTree()
        forest.append(tree)

    # Use the "shingle" generator to create rolling window
    #temp_data represents my aws_cpuutilization data
    points = rrcf.shingle(temp_data, size=shingle_size)

    # Create a dict to store anomaly score of each point
    avg_codisp = {}

    # For each shingle...
    for index, point in enumerate(points):
        # For each tree in the forest...
        for tree in forest:
          # If tree is above permitted size, drop the oldest point (FIFO)
          if len(tree.leaves) > tree_size:
             tree.forget_point(index - tree_size)
        # Insert the new point into the tree
        tree.insert_point(point, index=index)
        """Compute codisp on the new point and take the average among all 
         trees"""
        if not index in avg_codisp:
            avg_codisp[index] = 0
            avg_codisp[index] += tree.codisp(index) / num_trees
    values =[]   
    for key,value in avg_codisp.items():
        values.append(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in RandomCutForest. If you have labeled anomalies we recommend you use SageMaker Automatic Model Tuning (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning.html), and let SageMaker find the combination that works best.

Heuristically, if you know that your data has 0.4% of anomalies, for example, you would set the number of samples per tree to N = 1 / (0.4 / 100) = 250. The idea behind this is that each tree represents a sample of your data. Each datapoint in a tree is considered "normal". If your trees have too few points, e.g. 10, then most points will look different than these "normal" ones, i.e. they will have a high anomaly score.

The relation between the number of trees and the underlying data is more complex. As the range of "normal" points grows, you would want to have more trees.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i am using RRCF library and i am not using AWS services to find out anomalies rather than i am coding the entire thing my self. So i needed a way to generalize across the applications or a way to set the parameters automatically from the co_disp score. Like if mean , std of co_disp and with that i am going to set up my hyper parameters . Hope i get a Response . Thanks.